# Excel VBA macros have disappeared

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How it started:
Wanted to view Code window and Spreadsheet at same time.  In XL VBEditor, Dragged Code window, Project window, and Properties around on screen to accomplish this.  Pushed a few toggle buttons such as View Code, Show/Hide folders to see what they did.

What occurred:
Noticed that all modules still listed in project window, but when click on any one module name, the macro routines were missing on the module.  For the most part, some comments and the code 'Option Explicit' were still visible, but all the macros=subroutines gone.

More confusing:  SOMEtimes if I remove the code line 'Option Explicit', the macros on that particular module reappear.

MOST confusing:  If I find a module that shows one macro #1, I can try to write another macro (#2) on that module.  When I complete macro #2 which has form Sub NewMacroName(), ..., and End Sub,  the second macro #2 is present but the first macro #1 disappears! Remove Sub #2 and Sub #1 reappears

CONCLUSIONS SO FAR:
The macros are clearly hidden, not actually gone.
If I open the Object Browser, I can see a list of Global Classes (each one is a coding module).
If a click on one Global Class, I see a list of  Class Members (each one is a subroutine/macro).

I thought it wouldn't be impossible to work in this configuration, but it will be quite inconvenient.  Getting back to the original configuration would be a blessing.  In reality, either macro routines can't see the personal workbook, or they can't see specific personal macro routines.

Tried to talk with Microsoft about this, but after 30 minutes a service person came back on and said no one is answering today, try again another day.  On a workday, I got back to MSFT.  MSFT wants $499 to even discuss the problem.  Ouch!

Setup:  Windows 10 up to date, HP laptop less 6 months old,  Excel from Office 2019, although many macros/modules written from Excel 2010.  Everything was fine until I started moving window panes around.

Thanks in Advance for your helpful insights.

ADDENDUM:  18March2019:  Gave up on fixing the above problem while I was out of state working on a project.  Hoped that reinstalling Excel 2019 once I got home would clear the problem.  No such luck.  Resolved that I would have to search the internet stem to stern for solutions.
   One idea on the internet led me to:
Excel: Developer: VBEditor: Tools tab: Macros: all my Macros listed

Decided to arbitrarily pick one macro and hit Edit button.
Viola!  ALL of my macros became visible on all of the modules on all of my workbooks.  After less than an hour of replacing very minor code that was missing from personal code, I was back up and running normally.

Clearly clicking on
Excel: Developer: VBEditor: Tools tab: Macros: Edit one macro
Corrected something!

I figure that at least one expert on this web site recognizes what the problem was and will clue me in - so I don’t do it again!

Again, thanks in advance for your constructive replies!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly (and I suspect I'm not alone). Can you upload some screen captures to imgur.com and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1401664/edit) to link to them. Showing what you see and pointing out where you expect what would also be helpful.

Comment: In Excel main window, click on menu - View - Macros - View macros. If all macros are visible, you are safe, nothing has got deleted. It is just hidden. Comment below what you see there?

Comment: Following suggestion above: Personal Workbook, on worksheet, selected View Tab: Macros: View Macros --> see list macro routine names (presumably all).  If I run arbitrary macro it is there and does run until it stumbles due to a missing variable value.  But only that single macro shows on code sheet, not the ones I know are above/ below it on module sheet.  This confirms to me that the macros do exist, they are hidden.  Further, if on that module that shows a single macro, I add Sub Two_Dummy, then the first macro disappears.  If I delete Sub Two_Dummy, then the first macro reappears.

Comment: could you post a screen shot of your Visual Basic window?

Comment: First, you should take a backup of all your macros to ensure they don't totally disappear in this troubleshooting. As you said you can run each macro one by one, instead of running them, click on edit so that vb editor opens, then you copy entire macros, as many are available, and save them separtely in some text .bas or .vb file. Do this again and again by running different macros there, till you have saved all your macros. Then we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: could you check what files, if any, are there in  C:/Users/<YourUserName>/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel/XLSTART? If you have changed Excel's XLSTART from default to somewhere else, please look into that location rather. Current location of your XLSTART can be found by - 1. Open Visual Basic editor window. 2. Press Ctrl-G to open immediate mode, 3. type ? application.StartupPath   in that and press enter. The folder name will be showsn.

Comment: @Q.Reply,, it's difficult to find the issue, better you share Workbook on Drop Box or Cloud and let us examine and fix the bug!!