# Anyone sustain Excel VBA macro deletions due to security software?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have Excel VBA macros that have disappeared. They still exist, I just can't use them.

See my previous question "[Excel VBA macros have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/1401664/excel-vba-macros-have-disappeared)" that got no answer so far.

Do security software programs delete/mess with VBA macros - even if they don't tell you?  I am wondering if McAffee anti-virus software could be involved in my problem?

Thanks in advance for your helpful guiding light.

ADD:  VSRawat is exactly right, I see this as a different question which I posed because there was no conclusive answer received on the first question of 'disappearing' macros.

On this current question, I conclude from the answers that no one is having problems with anti-virus/security software gobbling up VBA macros.  Thus I consider this question closed.

My thanks again to VSRawat.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1403253/edit) to clarify it. If the macros exist, they haven't disappeared. What happens if you try to use them? Where should we see the query "Excel VBA macros have disappeared"? It might be useful for you to read [this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad He was referening to his previous post where he had elaborated. Link added for easy access.

Comment: @fixer1234 it is his own previously asked question. He didn't receive working answer there, so he is trying to find what could have caused it. There he was finding the solution to resolve the problem. Here he is asking what could have caused it. So it is a different question in essence, and is not duplicate.

Comment: @VSRawat, it's the same issue.  It would be better to edit the first question to focus that rather than ask a second version of it because the first didn't get an answer.

Comment: Explain that to him. What can I do or say in this? When someone is not getting answer to his question in 2-3 days and his work is stuck, he will obviously try other ways that he can think up of.

Answer (score 0):

You description clearly says that you were doing something when this happened.

So, it was some setting switched on or off that is causing all this.

You are also confirming that all macros are still present there and you can run them one by one, they are just not getting displayed properly as earlier.

So the question of any security software programs delete/mess with VBA macros doesn't even arise because no deletion/ messing up has taken place.

In any case, Excel macros are stored in Workbook file itself, .xls, .xlsx, .xlsb are all properietary file formats of Microsoft for which it doesn't officially release any specifications, other software wouldn't be able to handle these formats with authority and they don't want to get into trouble by touching these file and damaging them.

Macros are texts. Text contents are not virus/ torjan, malware, adware or anything harmful or irritating, so there is all the more no reason that any software will find any problem with that. In the rarest of the rare case that a macro saved in Microsoft format in its binary form appears like a virus signature, only then a software will touch it, But all security software give enough message about what they caught and they allow user to allow what they caught, or quarantine that for some 3 months, they normally don't summarily delete things.

So, I don't think, McAffee or windows defender or anything is causing it because nothing so drastic has happened.